How to transfer installed apps between multi-user accounts in my Lenovo Tab 8
I am in search of an answer from anyone who knows how to transfer installed apps from one multi-user account to another on a Lenovo Tab 8.
Please do so well, to direct me on this.

I didnt know you could have multiusers.  Does each user login/signin with different credentials?
